# How to fix error of incompatibility of versions google play services

Tags: firebase, admob, ionic4

My ionic app can't running on android devices and i get this error :

```
'Cordova Play Services Version Adapter' has detected an error. The following dependencies of 'Google Play Services' are not compatible: You have an incompatibility of versions with the following dependencies of 'Google Play Services':
    - 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4'
    - 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+'
    - 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+'
    - 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+'
    - 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+'
    - 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+'
```

It doesn't exists a version of 'Google Play Services' that includes all these dependencies.
All dependencies of 'Google Play Services' must have the same version.
The application may not compile."

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to find the file `platforms/android/project.properties` and update the lines

```
cordova.system.library.12=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.13=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.0.4
```

to

```
cordova.system.library.12=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+
cordova.system.library.13=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+
```

Comment: this did not help me.

Answer (score 2):

Selast has suggest a good manual solution for resolving this.

An alternative is to use a plugin which will automatically override the play services version so that everyone asks for the same version.

This plugin will provide that functionality:

[appfeel/cordova-play-services-version-adapter: Cordova/Ionic Google Play Services Versions Incompatibility Adapter](https://github.com/appfeel/cordova-play-services-version-adapter)

To use it just type this into the console:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-play-services-version-adapter
```